# What Azure service to use for DR strategy - Traffic Manager , App Gateway , Load balancer or Azure Front door in terms for HA and high resilience

Tags: azure, disaster-recovery

Azure DR strategy what to use Traffic Manager , App Gateway , Load balancer or Azure Front door in terms for HA and high resilience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft Azure services like Application Gateway, Front Door, Load Balancer and
Traffic Manager can be divided into two categories:

- **Global load-balancing services** such as Traffic Manager and Front Door distribute traffic from your end users across your regional backends, across clouds and even your hybrid on-premises services.
- **Regional load-balancing services** such as Load Balancers and Application Gateways provide the ability to distribute traffic to virtual machines (VMs) within a virtual network (VNETs) or service endpoints within a region.

When choosing a global load balancer between Traffic Manager and Azure Front Door for global routing, you should consider what’s similar and what’s different about the two services.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-lb-with-azure-app-delivery-suite#choosing-a-global-load-balancer

Here is an example of Microsoft Azure DR architecture with Application Gateway, Front Door, Load Balancer and Traffic Manager.

[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-lb-with-azure-app-delivery-suite
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/framework/resiliency/backup-and-recovery